# list all open files by ip

Tags: linux, ssh, netstat

Is there a way to show all open files by IP address on linux?
I use this:
netstat -atun | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n

to show all connections from IP sorted by number of connections.

How do I know what are these IP's hitting?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a way to identify the process that has the socket open in netstat, you could use the `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` to find what files that process has open. Of course, a lot of those files may not be accessed from the network - for example your typical apache server will have `/var/log/httpd/access_log` and `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and quite possibly some other files too. And of course, it will be a "moment in time", what file that process has open in 5 seconds or a millisecond from now may be quite a bit different.

I presume you don't just let anything/anyone access the server, so I'm guessing it's a webserver or some such, in which case, it would probably be easier to put some code into your web interface to track who does what.